# How to get the name of an active link using angular or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Please, help show the name of the active links to the inside toggle button.

```
<div class="bs-example">
<!-- Trigger Button HTML -->
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo" value="Toggle Button">Display here name of an active link </a>
<!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
<div id="toggleDemo" class="collapse in">
<li><a href="<?php echo $h->vars['1_url_link']; ?>" class="btn <?php echo $h->vars['link_active']; ?>" role="button"><?php echo $h->lang["1_name_link"]; ?></a>  </li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $h->vars['2_url_link']; ?>" class="btn <?php echo $h->vars['link_active']; ?>" role="button"><?php echo $h->lang["2_name_link"]; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $h->vars['3_url_link']; ?>" class="btn <?php echo $h->vars['link_active']; ?>" role="button"><?php echo $h->lang["3_name_link"]; ?></a> </li>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you already using Angular? Where's all your code and stuff. Controllers, Module etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using AngularJS, so I'm going to give a jQuery answer:

Give your anchor button an id that you can target, such as:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo" value="Toggle Button" id="#togglebtn">Display here name of an active link </a>
```

Then you can set the text with the following:

```
var btntext = $('.link_active').text();
$('#togglebtn').text(btntext);
```

**EDIT:**

If you have multiple buttons with the .link_active class, then you can be more specific like:

```
var btntext = $('#toggleDemo .link_active').text();
$('#togglebtn').text(btntext);
```

Think of jQuery selectors like you would use selectors in CSS.  If you want the .link_active buttons to be red in one area and blue in another, you'd add another selector to be more specific.  Works the same in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your help. He pulls the name of the link from another list of links and I get a double title in toggle button. Maybe there is a way to pull the title links to a specific ID or Class?

Comment: So there are multiple buttons with the .link_active class elsewhere on the page?

Comment: You're welcome. Please close the question by selecting the answer.